# Why isn't the chemical potential of photons equal to $\hbar\omega$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, photons, chemical-potential

I am confused about the chemical of photons. Specifically, I don't understand what's faulty with the following derivation:

Consider a black body at equilibrium temperature $T$, and let's focus on a particular mode with frequency $\omega$. This particular mode can be viewed as a thermodynamic system at equilibrium with the black body.

Since photons in this mode are spontaniously emitted and absorbed by the black body, I model the black body as a particle reservoir exchanging particles (photons) with the mode.

Since the mode has energy $N\hbar\omega$ where $N$ is the number of photons. Taking the derivative with respect to $N$ we get $\mu=\hbar\omega$.

Where's the error in this reasoning?

Comment: $\mu = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N} \right)_{V,S}$ In particular, the partial is taken at constant entropy.

Comment: The chemical potential of non-conserved particles is not a well defined concept. You need some conserved quantity to construct a chemical potential (e.g. the charge when considering a hot fermion/anti-fermion system, or the particle number when considering non-relativistic systems). If there is no such quantity, there is no generalization of a chemical potential.

Comment: @SebastianRiese photon number is conserved in free space, which is all we need. It may not be conserved at the boundry of a region, where photons may be emitted by some matterial for example, but provided this boundry represents a vanishing fraction of the total volume its effect can be neglected. This is essentially the same argument that allows us to avoid expicitly modelling the interactions that allow heat transfer between a resovoir and the system.

Comment: @jacob1729 I see, but what would be the entropy of a *mode*? Wouldn't it be zero since all particles in the mode are necessarily in the same state?

Comment: @BarAlon I'm not sure, which is why I haven't posted an answer! I do think it's non zero as the entropy of all of the modes together is certainly non-zero and I think they should simply add across modes (considered as distinct non-interacting systems like you say in your post). It should probably be proportional to $N$, which is why it changes when you add an extra photon to the mode.

Answer (score 1):

The chemical potential of a photon is 0 and this is how I like to think about it:

The energy ($E$) of a mode of a blackbody can be expressed as a function of entropy ($S$) only as the number of photons are summed over. Hence $\mu = \frac{\partial E}{ \partial N} = 0$. Please see the next paragraph for details.

At thermal equilibrium (Temperature $T$), the energy of a mode of the blackbody is calculated as $E = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(n)n\hbar \omega$ where $P(n)$ is probability of having $n$ photons in the mode. $P(n)$ is given by Boltzmann distribution i.e. $P(n)=e^{-n\beta \hbar \omega}(1-e^{-\beta \hbar \omega})$ where $\beta = 1/k_BT$. After evaluating the summation one gets $E = \frac{\hbar \omega}{e^{\beta \hbar \omega}-1}$. One can invert this equation to write $\frac{1}{T} = f(E)$. Since $\frac{1}{T} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial E}$, energy can be written as a function of entropy only.

Comment: Non-thermal radiation can have a non-zero chemical potential, for instance LEDs. See this highly cited paper https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3719/15/18/012/pdf, nice answer, just wanted to add this because it’s important distinction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: But the fact that the derivative of $S$ is a function of $E$ does not imply that $S$ itself is a function of $E$. In any case, can't the energy be written purely in terms of $N$ though? i.e. $E=N\hbar\omega$? By the same argument it would then follow that $\mu=\hbar\omega$ and $T,P=0$